# C# OLEDB DBF Querying issue with codepage invalid data

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf

Hello I'm trying to connect to a DBF and query it.

I use the following connectionstring:

```
 string s = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(this.ShapePathFileName) + "\\;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";
```

Then I want to fill a datatable it the result:

```
oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand);
((DbDataAdapter)oleDbDataAdapter).Fill(dataTable);
```

But I've in the results values like this:
"ÒoþÚ"

but in the file I've this:
"ãoçé"

also if in the SQL statement I've `WHERE name like '%é'` I get no results, but with `WHERE name like '%Ú'` I've results

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
Collate=YourDbCollation
```

or

```
CodePage=YourCodePage
```

in the query string.

Even better than that, try donwloading an usign

[VIsual FoxPro OleDB Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14839)

You have lot of samples of how the new query string should look like:

[Visual Fox Pro Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/visual-foxpro)

Comment: When I use: "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\\\server1\\Share\\;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;COLLATE='MACHINE';" I get "Could not find installable ISAM."